# Inner join of an EXCEPT subquery on column names that do not appear in the output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of students and classes. I would like to find what classes were dropped from one semester to another (and a similar query for classes added).

```
Student    Class       Semester
==============================
Alice      English     11
Alice      Geometry    11
Alice      English     12
Bob        Spanish     11
Bob        Spanish     12
```

My approach is to use an `except` (same as `minus`):

```
select distinct Class
from table
where table.Student = 'Alice'
and table.Semester = 11
except
select distinct Class
from table
where table.Student = 'Alice'
and table.Semester = 12
```

This works correctly, returning `Geometry`. However, I need to use this as a subquery like this:

```
select Student, string_agg(X.Class, ', ') as 'Deleted_Classes', 
count(X) as 'Num_deleted',
SemesterTable.Semester as semester, 
lag(Semester, 1) 
over (partition by StudentTable.Student 
order by SemesterTable.Semester) as Prev_Semester,
from 
StudentTable
SemesterTable
inner join (
<<<Same query from above>>>
) X on _______
where X.Num_deleted > 0
```

My problems is with the `____` section - inner joins can only be joined on columns that appear in the output. But my `except` query doesn't return the values of previous and current semesters (it might even return nothing at all if no classes were dropped). So how do I join the subquery into the main table? My desired output is:

```
Student     Semester     Prev Semester   Deleted_Classes
========================================================
Alice        12          11              Geometry
```

`Alice` appears because she had a change in her schedule, but `Bob` is omitted because there was no change in his schedule.

Comment: `EXCEPT` is ISO/ANSI SQL.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Not exists might work too, but how do I feed it the values for the current semester and previous semester

Comment: I suggest you stop trying to do everything at once and focus on a specific goal. Ignoring the fact that "semester" always belongs to a specific year (which adds more complication), what specific goal do you want to address first given your sample data (and adding more than a single student is HIGHLY recommended)? For example - find all dropped classes for "Fall" semester? Is "Spring" prior to "Fall"? Is there no "Summer" semester?

Comment: Thanks for encouraging - I edit the question to replace Semester with a numerical unique ID, which is how my actual data is structured. My goal is to return a table of students, semester ids and number of dropped classes relative to the prior semester. That table should only have rows when the number of dropped classes is at least 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this via `Left Join` with checking the availability of the next semester for a particular student via `exist` in `where`.

```
Select T.Student, T.Semester+1 As Semester, T.Semester As [Prev Semester], 
       string_agg(T.Class, ',') As Deleted_Classes
From Tbl As T Left Join Tbl As T1 On (T.Student=T1.Student 
                                      And T.Semester+1=T1.Semester
                                      And T.Class=T1.Class)
Where Exists (Select * From Tbl 
              Where Student=T.Student 
                    And Semester=T.Semester+1) And
      T1.Semester Is Null
Group by T.Student, T.Semester+1, T.Semester
```

If your semester ids are not increasing strictly, you can use the same logic via `cte` with `dense_rank` to order semesters according to your criteria for each student as follows:

```
With CTE As (
Select Student, Semester, Class, 
       Dense_Rank() Over (Partition by Student Order by Semester) As N
From Tbl
)
Select T.Student, Max(T2.Semester) As Semester, Max(T.Semester) As [Prev Semester], 
        string_agg(T.Class, ',') As Deleted_Classes
From CTE As T Left Join CTE As T1 On (T.Student=T1.Student 
                                      And T.N+1=T1.N
                                      And T.Class=T1.Class)
              Cross Apply (Select Distinct Semester 
                           From CTE 
                           Where Student=T.Student          
                                 And N=T.N+1) As T2
Where T1.N Is Null
Group by T.Student, T.N+1, T.N
```

Result:

| Student | Semester | Prev Semester | Deleted_Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 12 | 11 | Geometry |

to get both deleted classes and added classes with a single query, you can use the following:

```
With CTE As (
Select Student, Semester, Class, 
       Dense_Rank() Over (Partition by Student Order by Semester) As N
From Tbl
)
Select T.Student, Max(T1.Semester) As Semester, Max(T.Semester) As [Prev Semester], 
        Max(T2.Deleted_Classes) As Deleted_Classes, Max(T3.Added_Classes) As Added_Classes
From (Select Distinct Student, Semester, N From CTE) As T Cross Apply
     (Select Distinct Student, Semester, N From CTE Where Student=T.Student And N=T.N+1) As T1
              Outer Apply (Select Student, Semester, string_agg(Class, ', ') As Deleted_Classes
                           From CTE 
                           Where Student=T.Student          
                                 And N=T.N
                                 And Class Not In (Select Class From CTE Where Student=T.Student And N=T.N+1)
                           Group by Student, Semester) As T2
              Outer Apply (Select Student, Semester, string_agg(Class, ', ') As Added_Classes
                           From CTE 
                           Where Student=T.Student          
                                 And N=T.N+1
                                 And Class Not In (Select Class From CTE Where Student=T.Student And N=T.N)
                           Group by Student, Semester) As T3
Group by T.Student, T.N+1, T.N
Having Max(T2.Deleted_Classes) Is Not Null Or Max(T3.Added_Classes) Is Not Null
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e78d376f72cb76c9106dc1038e8215b7)

Result:

| Student | Semester | Prev Semester | Deleted_Classes | Added_Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 11 | 10 | Portuguese | English, Math |
| Alice | 12 | 11 | Geometry, Math | Biology, Geography |
| Bob | 12 | 11 | Portuguese | Math |

Comment: My semester ids are not strictly increasing and are unique to each student (imagine if some students were on a quarter systems while others on semester system, and some would take a semester off here and then), but I think i can work with this. Just need to have the current and previous semester id available.

Comment: then you could use "CTE" with "dense_rank" to order the semesters according to your criteria for each student, and then use these values instead of the semester in the left join.

Comment: @Ilya Voytov updated for both deleted and added classes.

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. I've never even heard of a cross apply/outer apply before. I was able to replicate this and it works perfectly (my actual data is far more complex with 7 table joins on a subquery result, so I was quite impressed that it just worked).

Answer (score 2):

Using a `NOT EXISTS` seems appropriate for this.

> ```
> create table StudentSemesters (
>  Student varchar(30),
>  Class varchar(30),
>  Semester int
> );
>
> insert into StudentSemesters
> (Student, Class, Semester) values
>   ('Alice',     'English',     11) 
> , ('Alice',     'Geometry',    11)
> , ('Alice',     'English',     12)
> , ('Bob',       'Spanish',     11) 
> , ('Bob',       'Spanish',     12) 
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select Student
> , Semester+1 as [Semester] 
> , Semester as [Prev_Semester]
> , STRING_AGG(Class, ', ') as [Deleted_Classes] 
> from StudentSemesters t
> where not exists (
>     select 1
>     from StudentSemesters t2
>     where t2.Student = t.Student
>       and t2.Class = t.Class
>       and t2.Semester = t.Semester+1
>     )
>   and exists (
>     select 1
>     from StudentSemesters t2
>     where t2.Student = t.Student
>       and t2.Semester = t.Semester+1
>     )
> group by Student, Semester;
> ```

| Student | Semester | Prev_Semester | Deleted_Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 12 | 11 | Geometry |

> ```
> select 
>   Student
> , Semester as [Semester] 
> , Semester-1 as [Prev_Semester]
> , STRING_AGG(Class, ', ') as [Added_Classes] 
> from StudentSemesters t
> where not exists (
>     select 1
>     from StudentSemesters t2
>     where t2.Student = t.Student
>       and t2.Class = t.Class
>       and t2.Semester = t.Semester-1
>     )
> group by Student, Semester;
> ```

| Student | Semester | Prev_Semester | Added_Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 11 | 10 | English, Geometry |
| Bob | 11 | 10 | Spanish |

**Combined, using full join**

> ```
> select 
>   coalesce(t1.Student, t2.Student) as Student
> , coalesce(t2.Semester, t1.Semester+1) as [Semester] 
> , coalesce(t1.Semester, t2.Semester-1) as [Prev_Semester]
> , STRING_AGG(t1.Class, ', ') as [Deleted_Classes] 
> , STRING_AGG(t2.Class, ', ') as [Added_Classes]  
> from StudentSemesters t1
> full join StudentSemesters t2
>   on t2.Student = t1.Student
>  and t2.Class = t1.Class
>  and t2.Semester = t1.Semester+1
> where (t1.Class is null or
>  (t2.Class is null
>   and exists (
>     select 1
>     from StudentSemesters t3
>     where t3.Student = t1.Student
>       and t3.Semester = t1.Semester+1
>     )))
> group by 
>   coalesce(t1.Student, t2.Student), 
>   coalesce(t2.Semester, t1.Semester+1), 
>   coalesce(t1.Semester, t2.Semester-1) 
> order by Student, Semester;
> ```

| Student | Semester | Prev_Semester | Deleted_Classes | Added_Classes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 11 | 10 | *null* | English, Geometry |
| Alice | 12 | 11 | Geometry | *null* |
| Bob | 11 | 10 | *null* | Spanish |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88666f7cec9f239f78f7f1c425186d8f)*

Comment: I believe this is the same as the `except` query that I provided, which is already functional. The challenge is to create a master query that will return the desired output - table of all students, all semesters, and a column with a string of all classes deleted in that semester.

Comment: Ok, updated. Now with aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Last question, and I bet one that you have anticipated - how would I combine both into a single query? My guess make each a subquery that outputs the aggregated string?

Comment: The method  with the `NOT EXISTS` isn't great for combining.  But I've added a solution with a `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: This works, and is perfect if you want a separate row for additions and deletions. For my use case, the cross apply solution works a bit better as it combines the two Alice rows into a single one, but thank you so much for working through the problem. Wish I could accept both answers!

Comment: @IlyaVoytov That's ok. Btw, the group by of the FULL JOIN solution has changed to get single rows per (student, semester)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240543/discussion-between-ilya-voytov-and-lukstorms).

Answer (score 2):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        min(Semester) over (partition by Student, Class) as minSemester,
        max(Semester) over (partition by Student, Class) as maxSemester,
        count(*) over (partition by Student, Class) as cntSemester
    from T
    where Semester in (11, 12)
)
select Student, Class,
    case when minSemester = 12 then 'Added'   else '' end as Added,
    case when maxSemester = 11 then 'Dropped' else '' end as Dropped
from data
where maxSemester = 11;
```

There's all kinds of information you could derive from these values. For example, knowing that the latest semester was not 12 implies that class was dropped. You can do similar for additions.

Answer (score 0):

Group rows ordered by Student and Semester according to Student, and in each group, group rows by Semester and perform inter-row calculations. The difference between the set of Classes in the spring semester and that in the fall semester is the newly added classes, and the difference between the fall semester and the spring semester contains the cancelled classes. It is a hassle to code this in SQL because you will need the window function, CROSSAPPLY and OUTERAPPLY. The SQL statement will be lengthy and difficult to understand. An alternative is to move data out of database and process it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easy to be integrated into a Java program and generate simple code. It can get this done with only two lines of code

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =MSSQL.query@x("select * from Classes order by 1,3") |
| 2 | =A1.group@o(#1).conj(~.group@o(#1,#3;~.(#2)).new(Student,#2[+1]:Semester,#2:Prev_Semester,(#3#3[+1]).concat@c():Deleted_Classes,(#3[+1]#3).concat@c():Added_Classes).m(:-2)) |